# ng7 dynamic breadcrum issue

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

I have implemented the breadcrumb using ng7-dynamic-breadcrumb. I stuck in level2 navigation in my CRUD application.

Expected is, when url changes, breadcrumb should update accordingly.

Ex: 
Working URL : `http://localhost:4200/technicalSettings/disciplines?disciplineId=5250 this is working fine like

`Disciplines`

But when I change the URL for create operation using ng-templates like

```
http://localhost:4200/technicalSettings/disciplines?disciplineId=5250&disciplineView=create
```

Expected breadcrumb is `Disciplines >  create`

unfortunately it is not working. Expert advise please?

**TS Routing**

```
const technicalSettingsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: "disciplines",
        component: DisciplinesComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'disciplines',
          breadcrumb: [
            {
              label: 'Disciplines',
              url: ''
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        path: "disciplines:disciplineId",
        component: DisciplinesComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Disciplines',
          breadcrumb: [
            {
              label: 'disciplines',
              url: 'disciplines'
            },
            {
              label: 'page {{customText}}',
              url: ''
            }
          ]
        },
      },
      { path: "", component: DisciplinesComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'disciplines' } }
```

**TS component**

```
 updateBreadcrumb(): void {
    const breadcrumbs  =  [
      {
        label: 'Disciplines',
        url: 'disciplines'
      },
      {
        label: 'Create New',
        url: ''
      }
    ];
    this.ngDynamicBreadcrumbService.updateBreadcrumb(breadcrumbs);
  }

 disciplineCrudViews(view: any, openStatus: boolean) {
    this.openView = openStatus;
    this.switchView = view;
    if(view == "create") {
     this.updateBreadcrumb();
    }

    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineId: this.selectedId, disciplineView: view } });
  }

   onRowClicked(event: any) {
    this.isRowSelected = true;
    this.selectedId = event.data.id; //event.id;
    this.selectedItem = event;
    console.log(this.selectedItem);
    this.dataService.set(event);
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineId: this.selectedId } });

  }

 ngOnInit() {

        const breadcrumb =  {customText: 'This is Custom Text', dynamicText: 'Level 2 '};
      this.ngDynamicBreadcrumbService.updateBreadcrumbLabels(breadcrumb);
    }
```

Comment: Please create stackblitz example.

Comment: Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng7-dynamic-breadcrumb-b4hphz?file=src/app/page/page.component.html.  when I click "+" button. it opens the create view in same page. Breadcrumb needs to be update like Page1 / Create" and when we click on Page1 only "Page1" should display.

Comment: Ya. Understood, I'll update you shortly

Comment: @Rama Mohan Thank you. Waiting for your updates.

Answer (score 0):

@klmuralimohan New feature has been implemented available in [ng-dynamic-breadcrumb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb), please check and let me know if there is any issue.

Update the Breadcrumb using NgDynamicBreadcrumbService

```
import { NgDynamicBreadcrumbService } from 'ng-dynamic-breadcrumb';
constructor(private ngDynamicBreadcrumbService: NgDynamicBreadcrumbService) { }

  updateBreadcrumb(): void {
    const breadcrumbs  =  [
      {
        label: 'page {{pageOneID}}',
        url: '/page1/:pageOneID'
      },
      {
        label: 'page {{pageTwoID}}',
        url: 'page1/:pageOneID/page2/:pageTwoID'
      },
      {
        label: 'page {{pageThreeID}}',
        url: 'page1/:pageOneID/page2/:pageTwoID/page3/:pageThreeID'
      },
      {
        label: 'Update Breadcrumb',
        url: ''
      }
    ];
    this.ngDynamicBreadcrumbService.updateBreadcrumb(breadcrumbs);
  }
```

Stackblitz Demo URL: https://ng-dynamic-breadcrumb.stackblitz.io/page1/1/page2/2/page3/3

NPM avilable version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb/v/2.0.1

Comment: Firstly thanks for the quick update. I'm using Angular 7 version application. I have updated the above changes unfortunately not working. Throwing error "WARNING in ./node_modules/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb/fesm5/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb.js 47:68-86
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'"

Comment: Ya... Currently, the NPM Module dependent on Angular 8. EOD I'll try to implement for angular 7 as well.

Comment: For Angular 7  Please use ng-dynamic-breadcrumb 1.0.6  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb/v/1.0.6

Comment: It is not working.  I have updated the queryparams on click button so the url looks like "http://localhost:4200/technicalSettings/disciplines?disciplineId=5250&disciplineView=create" that breadcrumb is loading level2 menu

Comment: Please check Stackblitz Example:  https://ng-dynamic-breadcrumb.stackblitz.io/page1/1/page2/2/page3/3  and check the https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage3%2Fpage3.component.ts updateBreadcrumb() function

Comment: Still, You are facing issues please create stackblitz example!                                                  Note: Query Strings You should pass the dynamic data through updateBreadcrumb()

Comment: Here the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb-6pvtqh?file=src/app/page/page.component.ts. If you see in the first page component, I have updated your breadcrum level2 logic with route params as well. without route params on first click the updatebreadrumb() it is working fine. But when I update the route params, on first click level2 is not working, it works only one second click. This is the issue on your example. But In my application, level2 navigation not at all working...

Comment: Issue is when updating the route params and updatebreadcrumb data simultaneously, it is not working. Otherwise only breadcrumb update it is working fine. Any clue?

Comment: Getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'page1/1/page2/2'
 Please check and try to resolve this !.

Comment: Please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb-6pvtqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage%2Fpage.component.html. I'm testing only on first page. update Breadcrumb is working only on second click.  Issue is when updating the route params and updatebreadcrumb data simultaneously, it is not working. Without route params is working fine.